# Visualize graph on website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sigma.js

When I export from Gephi to Sigma.js and open my graph using Google Chrome, it does not show (only shows the default right-side Sigma.js -panel).

How to make a web-based network graph in Gephi (like [this example](http://visual-baseball.com/gephi/us_house/network/#H.R.%205629:%20Strengthening%20Domestic%20Nuclear%20Security%20Act%20of%202014))?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried opening your visualization in Firefox or any other browser? As far as I know, Chrome will not render local js from Sigma for the sake of security. Try another browser or upload your work to github (example: http://mamamot.github.io/vncollocations/).